# The linear combination of two vectors $cv + dw$ in $R^2$ lies on the line passing through v and w when $ c + d = 1$

Tags: linear-algebra

I am going through Gilbert Strang's book Introduction to Linear Algebra Edition 4. I need help with one of the questions in the exercise.

It asks to draw the line of all the combinations $cv + dw$ such that $c + d = 1$. I am able to verify that all such linear combinations of v and w indeed lie on the line passing through v and w in the following way:
Let the tail point of v be $(x_1, y_1)$ and w be $(x_2, y_2)$.
So, the equation of the line would be
$ y - y_1 = \frac{y_2 - y_1}{x_2 - x_1}(x - x_1)$

It can be verified that the point $(cx_1 + dx_2, cy_1 + dy_2)$ satisfies the equation of the line. But is there any **geometric meaning or intuition** through which it can be realized that such linear combinations would lie on this line?

[image]

This shows the linear combination $u$ when $c = d = 1/2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One is right there in the diagram in your question. From the parallelogram rule we can see that the dotted segment corresponds to $\mathbf d = \mathbf w-\mathbf v$ (or $\mathbf v-\mathbf w$, depending on the direction you’re going). The line consists of the points that can be reached by adding some multiple of $\mathbf d$ to $\mathbf v$, i.e., $\mathbf v+\lambda(\mathbf w-\mathbf v) = (1-\lambda)\mathbf v+\lambda\mathbf w$. What this says is that whatever proportion of $\mathbf w$ you’re adding, to stay on the line you have to take away that same proportion of $\mathbf v$, and so the coefficients stay balanced.

Another way to look at it is that the line through $\mathbf v$ and $\mathbf w$ is the image of the line $x+y=1$ under a linear transformation that maps $(1,0)$ to $\mathbf v$ and $(0,1)$ to $\mathbf w$. This transformation maps the point $(x,y)$ to $x\mathbf v+y\mathbf w$, but you’ve still got the constraint that $x+y=1$: because of the linearity of the transformation, that doesn’t change.

Incidentally, this is called an *affine combination* of $\mathbf v$ and $\mathbf w$. You’ll encounter these with more points or vectors in other contexts as well.

Comment: what is d? I'm confused.